# Rule-based symbology based on current selection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, symbology, oracle-spatial, rule-based

I have two oracle layer (point(**p1**) and polygon(**pl1**)). I want to build a rule-based symbology which is based on current selection on two cases:

*Case 1*- When I select a point from table **p1**, I want that the polygons from table **pl1** to be coloured differently based one the relation that they have with table **p1** which is **p1.id_b=pl1.id_b** (one to many).

*Case 2*- When I select a polygon from table **pl1** other polygons from the same layer that are related to current selection to be coloured differently. Relation between polygons is on the field **pl1.id_group**, so polygons are grouped by the same **pl1.id_group** (one to many).

Software used is QGIS.

[image]

For illustration I select point one and the related polygons are coloured differently from the others.

Comment: What if two cases occur? For example, for three colored polygons based-on the selected point in the image, what if you select one of them while the point is already selected?

Answer (score 7):

**Solution for Case 1**:

- Add two symbol layers to the polygon layer as in the image.
  [image]
- Open `Based-on selected points` rule, open expression window for `Filter`.
- Go to `Function Editor` tab and add the following script as function.

  ```py
  from qgis.core import *
  from qgis.gui import *

  @qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
  def related_rule_based(layer_name, field1, field2, feature, parent):
      layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
      selected_features = layer.selectedFeatures()
      if selected_features:
          feat = selected_features[0]
          if feat[field1] == feature[field2]:
              return True
          else:
              return False
  ```
- Click `Save and Load Functions`. Then, in `Expression` tab, enter the next  line: (`p1`: point layer name, first `id_b`: field in point layer, second `id_b`: field in polygon layer)

  ```py
  related_rule_based('p1', 'id_b', 'id_b')
  ```

This solution is for just one selected point. If you select more points, one polygon group will remain selected.

[image]

---

**Solution for Case 2**:

- Add one more rule to the polygon layer.

[image]

- Enter the following expression as rule.

  ```py
  related_rule_based(@layer_name, 'id_b', 'id_b')
  ```

Note: If two cases occur, one of both will be effective.

[image]

Comment: What if i it has to go check in more then on field for matching value p1.id_b=pl1.id_b1 or p1.id_b=pl1.id_b2 or p1.id_b=pl1.id_b3.....p1.id_b=pl1.id_bn or vice versa pl1.id_b=p1.id_b1 or pl1.id_b=p1.id_b2 or pl1.id_b=p1.id_b3.....pl1.id_b=p1.id_bn

Comment: You can add more parameters to function definition (`field3`, `field4`, ...) and more conditions to `if` statement. You can also create a separate function for case 2.

Answer (score 5):

This script creates a rule based style which refreshes upon the selection of a feature with the logic you described.You only need to enter the layer names below and run it in QGIS.

```
class Restyler:
    def __init__(self, polygonLayerName, pointLayerName):
        self.polygonLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(polygonLayerName)[0]
        self.pointLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(pointLayerName)[0]

        self.polygonLayer.selectionChanged.connect(self.polygonSelected)
        self.pointLayer.selectionChanged.connect(self.pointSelected)
        self.addRules()

    def addRules(self):
        layer = self.polygonLayer
        symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
        renderer = QgsRuleBasedRenderer(symbol)
        root_rule = renderer.rootRule()
        rule = root_rule.children()[0].clone()
        rule.setFilterExpression('"id_b" = @selected_id_b')
        rule.symbol().setColor(QColor('pink'))

        rule2 = rule.clone()
        rule2.setFilterExpression('"id_group" = @selected_id_group')
        root_rule.appendChild(rule)
        root_rule.appendChild(rule2)
        layer.setRenderer(renderer)
        iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())

    def pointSelected(self):
        if self.pointLayer.selectedFeatureCount() == 1:
            selectedIdb = self.pointLayer.selectedFeatures()[0]['id_b']
            QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable(QgsProject.instance(),'selected_id_b', selectedIdb)
            QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable(QgsProject.instance(),'selected_id_group', '')
            print("Point selected. id_b: {}".format(selectedIdb))
            self.polygonLayer.triggerRepaint()
        else:
            print("Error. One feature should be selected")
            QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable(QgsProject.instance(),'selected_id_group', '')
            QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable(QgsProject.instance(),'selected_id_b', '')

        self.polygonLayer.triggerRepaint()

    def polygonSelected(self):
        if self.polygonLayer.selectedFeatureCount() == 1:
            selectedIdGroup = self.polygonLayer.selectedFeatures()[0]['id_group']
            QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable(QgsProject.instance(),'selected_id_group', selectedIdGroup)
            QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable(QgsProject.instance(),'selected_id_b', '')
            print("Polygon selected. id_group: {}".format(selectedIdGroup))
        else:
            print("Error. One feature should be selected")
            QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable(QgsProject.instance(),'selected_id_group', '')
            QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable(QgsProject.instance(),'selected_id_b', '')

        self.polygonLayer.triggerRepaint()

#you only need to input your layer names
polygonLayerName = 'wojewodztwa'
pointLayerName = 'testcsv_geocoded'

restyler = Restyler(polygonLayerName, pointLayerName)
```

[image: result]

Comment: What if i it has to go check in more then on field for matching value p1.id_b=pl1.id_b1 or p1.id_b=pl1.id_b2 or p1.id_b=pl1.id_b3.....p1.id_b=pl1.id_bn or vice versa pl1.id_b=p1.id_b1 or pl1.id_b=p1.id_b2 or pl1.id_b=p1.id_b3.....pl1.id_b=p1.id_bn

Comment: I wrote this as an example. If you need any other logic you can implement it. If you have trouble implementing anything specifically then feel free to ask.